# PhpStorm: minifying all .SCSS files into a single .CSS file using watchify.js?

Tags: sass, npm, phpstorm, node-sass, watchify

I am developing a browser application using a combination of the following npm build tools

- Browserify
- Coffeeify
- Watchify

The scripts part of my package.json file is:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "browserify -t coffeeify init.coffee -o ../www/bundle.js",
    "watch": "watchify -t coffeeify init.coffee -o ../www/bundle.js"
  }
```

So far, I have configured my project so that before I start working on it, I enter the "npm run watch" command and all CoffeeScript files are automatically bundled into the bundle.js file whenever I update one. Now, I additionally want to have several .SCSS files that get automatically compiled into .CSS files and then all bundled and minified into a min.css file. And, ideally I want to accomplish this without having to enter commands other than then one I'm already entering for my CS files ("npm run watch").

Here are my package.json devDependencies:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "coffee-script": "^1.10.0",
    "coffeeify": "^2.0.1",
    "browserify": "^12.0.1",
    "watchify": "^3.6.0",
    "node-sass": "^3.4.2",
    "yuicompressor": "^2.4.8"
  }
```

So far, I am at the point where I am successfully compiling my .SCSS files into .CSS files using PhpStorm's file watcher and the node-sass npm module. After some reading, I decided to use the yui compressor (it's installed as a Node module too, as you can see above). However, after a lot of searching, I couldn't find a good description of how to do this.

Am I supposed to update the:

```
"watch": "watchify -t coffeeify init.coffee -o ../www/bundle.js"
```

line in my package.json file? If so, how?

I want the final result to be such that whenever a file from the SCSS folder is changed, the min.css file in some other folder is automatically recompiled.

(I don't necessarily insist on using the yui compressor, if there is a better option for my purposes.)